# Rank an SQL table with MYSQL, ranked by score, WHERE game = x

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to build a really simple online functionality system. One of the queries that this system must handle is the returning of a scoreboard (all of the players scores, ordered and ranked). I know basic sql queries, but i'm completely lost when it comes to sub queries and variables within queries etc.

The table only has three columns. game, user_id, score. The table will let people upload and download scores for any game. I need to work out how to create a query that returns only the users from the game being queried, orders the players by score, then ranks them so duplicate scores will have the same rank. Here's a brief example of the desired outcome:

TABLE

```
user       game       score

fred       A           100         
bill       A           78          
john       A           78          
dave       B           71          
terry      B           60          
jean       B           60          
tom        A           60 
nick       A           57
```

DESIRED OUTPUT

```
user      score       rank

fred       100         1
bill       78          2
john       78          2
tom        60          4
nick       57          5
```

CURRENT OUTPUT ** TAKES INTO ACCOUNT THE GAMES IT SHOULD IGNORE

```
user      score       rank

fred       100         1
bill       78          2
john       78          2
tom        60          5
nick       57          8
```

This is currently the query that works the best:

```
SELECT @rank:=@rank+1 AS ranking, user_id, score
FROM score_table , (SELECT @rank:=1) AS i
WHERE game='A' 
ORDER BY score DESC
```

But the rank seems to take into account other games, which ruins the rankings. Other queries i've found have ranked correctly but not eliminated the other games (again, taking the other games scores into account when ranking.

Again, the above is an example I tweaked, as I have no idea how to use the @ variables, sub queries etc.

Many thanks,

- Dan.

Comment: Just simply ordering your ORDER BY statement can do that. "Order by score, rank". That will return your set ordered by score, then by rank. So if scores are equal, they will be ordered by rank. And so on.

Comment: Can one user has more than one score for one game?

Comment: But there isn't an existing rank column - the examples I've looked at seem to create some form of rank variable whilst sorting the array. Once of the examples kept the rank the same for matching scores, as i showed in the example above, but they didnt let me add a WHERE game=x anywhere without the query breaking.

Comment: Sorry, @barrel, yeah that's the idea. Any number of scores per game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show the same rank for same score you can use case and additional variable for checking same rank

```
SELECT ranking,user,score FROM
(SELECT 
@rank:=case when score =@s then @rank else @rank+1 end AS ranking,
@s:=score,
user, score,game
FROM tablename , (SELECT @rank:=0,@s:=0) AS i
ORDER BY score DESC
) new_alias
WHERE game='A'
```

### [Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8fe4a0/3)

**Edit from comments**

### [Updated Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d533e0/2)

Comment: Where does the table name go?

Comment: Found that the table is 't' within this. Please highlight this :)

Comment: @DanielPrice i have updated my answer put your table name in query whee your find tablename

Comment: This fix still somehow doesnt work if there are games with scores higher than your games highest score.

Comment: What do you mean by *games with scores higher than your games highest score* it isn't in your question

Comment: In the DEMO change freds game to B to see what i mean.

Comment: Yes! Absolutely brilliant, thank you! I was close to changing to a simple sql query, then doing the rest with PHP. Awesome. Thank you very much!